# How do I reuse the cache from a `RUN --mount=type=cache` docker build?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-buildkit

I'm using the new experimental docker buildkit syntax to do a multistage build, as so:

Dockerfile:

```
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/home/build/.build-cache,gid=1000,uid=1001 ./build
```

bash:

```sh
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build .
```

Works great locally. On CI I get a new docker environment every time, so no caching.

I can export and import files into the env, but I don't know where the cache is located. Any ideas?

Or should I be exporting/importing the cache via some docker command? I've read https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#specifying-external-cache-sources and https://github.com/moby/buildkit#export-cache but it's not clear to me which is buildkit specific, which docker specific or if either really applies to this cache mounted into the Dockerfile RUN command.

I have added a public gist here of a failing test demonstrating what I was hoping for:
https://gist.github.com/Mahoney/85e8549892e0ae5bb86ce85339db1a71/6308f1bdb062a8982017193b96d61ec00a7698c5

And this later revision works, but I'm not happy with it - too much bootstrapping:
https://gist.github.com/Mahoney/85e8549892e0ae5bb86ce85339db1a71

Comment: You can use buildx w/ docker like `docker buildx build ...` and export / import the layer cache(s) from a registry, filesystem, or docker inline in your final image. https://medium.com/titansoft-engineering/docker-build-cache-sharing-on-multi-hosts-with-buildkit-and-buildx-eb8f7005918e and https://github.com/docker/buildx have more info.

Comment: Thanks, will review - I felt there must be something I'm missing.

Comment: Just to follow up on this - the problem is that using gradle in a multi project build, layer caching isn't that useful, as I pretty much have to do a `COPY . .`, blowing away all layer caching every time anything changes. There are ways to gain from layer caching, but they are a pain to maintain. Sharing the gradle user home directory is by some distance the most sane way to cache.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any way to extract this specific cache from the general docker working files.

However, you can of course backup the whole of `/var/lib/docker`. This doesn't work for CircleCI's remote docker engine, because you don't have sudo access, but does work for GitHub Actions where you do.

See here for an example:
https://github.com/Mahoney-playground/docker-cache-action

Comment: There's an issue raised by the buildkit team, so with a better than normal chance of being implemented, to make it possible to control what host directory gets mounted as the cache dir:
https://github.com/moby/buildkit/issues/1512

Comment: and now there is if you use `docker buildx build`

Comment: it's 2023. The issue is still open.
In other news, are you certain that `/var/lib/docker` is the directory?

Comment: @Naftali what is it? export-cache is not it